# How to remove a single bar in a barchart in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to create a barchart that show the percentage of patients with a complication (2) within each group. However, I only want to see the bar that shows the percentage of patients within each group *with* a complication, not the bar that shows the ones without a complication.

This is what the code looks like:

```
DiabetesAndCRC3_only_rectal %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x= complications,  group=Diabetes_status)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y = ..prop.., fill = factor(..x..)), stat="count") +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(..prop..), y= ..prop.. ), 
            stat= "count", vjust = -.5) +
  labs(y = "Percent", fill="Diabetes_status") +
  facet_grid(~Diabetes_status) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

[image: The bar-chart]

I tried to just filter for complications == "2" but then they all adds up to 100%. And I want to show the proportion within each group

Comment: I am recieving this error message when I try the code:

Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `share = n/sum(n)`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: Diabetes_status = Normal HbA1c.
Caused by error in `sum()`:
! invalid 'type' (closure) of argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way is to modify your existing code so that the undesired bars are set to transparent:

```
# note: after_stat(variable.name) is the updated & now recommended replacement
# for ..variable.name..

sample.data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x= factor(complications),  group=Diabetes_status,
             alpha = ifelse(after_stat(x) == 2, 1, 0))) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y = after_stat(prop)), 
           stat="count") +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(after_stat(prop)), y= after_stat(prop)), 
            stat= "count", vjust = -.5) +
  labs(y = "Percent with complications") +
  facet_grid(~Diabetes_status) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  scale_alpha_identity() +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1.5, 2.5))
```

Though in general, I think it's cleaner to pre-calculate & simply pass the results to ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)

sample.data %>%
  group_by(Diabetes_status, complications) %>%
  summarise(n = n(), .groups = "drop_last") %>%
  mutate(p = n/sum(n)) %>%
  filter(complications == 2) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Diabetes_status, y = p, label = scales::percent(p))) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(vjust = -.5) +
  labs(y = "Percent with complications") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

[image: side by side rseults]

Data:

```
set.seed(123)
sample.data <- data.frame(Diabetes_status = rep(c("Normal", "High", "T2D"), each = 100),
                          complications = sample(c(1, 2), size = 300, replace = TRUE))
```

p.s. I'm taking a guess at your data structure, so if the above doesn't work for you, you may wish to edit your question (don't paste into comments) with your output from `dput(DiabetesAndCRC3_only_rectal)`.